# How to set up django-admin.py on windows vista?

Tags: windows, django, path

I manage to install Django after some struggles by using setup.py install on Windows Vista

Now I tried to use django-admin.py but it is not working.

According to this document,

http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/django-admin/

> The django-admin.py  script should be
>   on your system path if you installed
>   Django via its setup.py  utility. If
>   it’s not on your path, ...
>
> For Windows users, who do not have
>   symlinking functionality available,
>   you can copy django-admin.py  to a
>   location on your existing path or edit
>   the PATH settings (under Settings -
>   Control Panel  - System - Advanced -
>   Environment...) to point to its
>   installed location.

I checked Computer>properties>Environment Variables, but path to django-admin.py is not in anywhere.

So I added C:\Python25\Lib\site-packages\django\bin which is the folder of django-admin.py in User variables for shin
Variable PATH, Value  C:\Program Files\Google\google_appengine\;C:\Python25\Lib\site-packages\django\bin\

Am I supposed to add to System variables??

But it still does not work.

Could anyone tell me how to add the Path in Environment Variables please?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

I think you shoukd also try adding your python location to PATH.

However, if your webserver runs under a different user account to your own, you'll need to add it either System variables, or the specific user running the webserver.

Answer (score 1):

Click ‘New’ and enter PATH for ‘variable name’ and c:\Python27\ for ‘Variable value’.

Answer (score 0):

add your `%Python Path%\Scripts` which cinatins file "**django-admin.py**" into your system environement variables **"PATH"**,that's all...(if you setup Django by it's "**setup.py**")